# I don't know which is correct in this sentence, "rose" or "raised"

Tags: grammar

I was wondering in this sentence whether to use *rose* or *raised*:

> Yes, they said she rose from the dead to haunt her husband.

Answer (score 5):

[*rise*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rise), intransitive verb (past tense: *rose*)

> to move upward; to awaken; to return from death.

[*raise*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raise), transitive verb (past tense: *raised*)

> to lift something or someone to a higher, or more upright, position.

If the subjects of the verb are lifting themselves, you need "rise"; if they are lifting someone or something else, you need "raise".

In this case, they are lifting themselves up from being dead, so it's "rise", which has the past tense "rose", so *She rose from the dead*.

Comment: The person who cast the magic spell to make the dead woman walk again *raised* her from the dead.

But yes, as the other answer said, she *rose* from the dead.

Comment: There is also the variation *arose*